# PLS-00103 error encountered while executing a script

Tags: oracle, toad

I am running into error when I execute the below script. I used to the run the same script all the time but never had an issue. I hope my question is well edited with proper formatting and clarity.

[Error] PLS-00103 (15: 47): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure subtype type  current

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_TABLE (
   v_process_period   IN VARCHAR2,
   v_loop             IN VARCHAR2)
AS
   v_cnt1                INTEGER := 0;
   v_prpr_id             VARCHAR2 (12) := NULL;
   v_pcp_prpr_id         VARCHAR2 (12) := NULL;
   v_prpr_mctr_val1      VARCHAR2 (4) := NULL;
   v_Secondary_idcd_id   VARCHAR2 (10) := NULL;
   v_primary_idcd_id     VARCHAR2 (10) := NULL;
   v_event1              VARCHAR2 (30) := NULL;
   v_event2              VARCHAR2 (30) := NULL;
   v_event3              VARCHAR2 (30) := NULL;
   v_event4              VARCHAR2 (30) := NULL;
   v_er_flag             VARCHAR2 (10) := 'NO';
   v_rec_cnt             INTEGER := 0;
   v_place_of_service    VARCHAR2 (2) := NULL;
   V_prpr_mctr_type      VARCHAR2 (4) := NULL;
   V_prcf_mctr_spec      VARCHAR2 (4) := NULL;
   V_paid_tot            NUMBER (18, 4);
   V_copay_tot           NUMBER (18, 4);
   V_ded_tot             NUMBER (18, 4);
   V_coins_tot           NUMBER (18, 4);
   V_risk_wh_tot         NUMBER (18, 4);
   V_allow_tot           NUMBER (18, 4);
   v_cob_tot             NUMBER (18, 4);
   v_cob_hdr             NUMBER (18, 4);
   v_denied              VARCHAR2 (1);
   V_er_cnt              INTEGER := 0;
   V_er_cnt1             INTEGER := 0;
   V_er                  VARCHAR2 (30) := NULL;
   V_rad                 VARCHAR2 (30) := NULL;
   V_ipa                 VARCHAR2 (4) := NULL;
   V_clhp_fac_type       VARCHAR2 (2) := NULL;
   V_clhp_bill_class     VARCHAR2 (1) := NULL;
   V_clhp_frequency      VARCHAR2 (1) := NULL;
   V_clhp_adm_source     VARCHAR2 (1) := NULL;
   V_clhp_dc_stat        VARCHAR2 (2) := NULL;
   V_clhp_dc_dt          DATE := NULL;
   V_agrg_id             VARCHAR2 (4) := NULL;
   v_pos_count           INTEGER := 0;
   v_global_cnt          INTEGER := 0;
   v_drg                 VARCHAR2 (3) := NULL;
   V_nwst_pfx            VARCHAR2 (4) := NULL;
   v_new_nwnw_id         VARCHAR2 (12) := NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the rest of the script? This is a syntax issue. Please look at the following examples for more information:

[create oracle package encountered PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231788/create-oracle-package-encountered-pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol-create)

[PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967543/pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol-end-of-file-when-expecting-one-of-the-follow)

[create oracle package encountered PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231788/create-oracle-package-encountered-pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol-create)

[PLS-00103 Oracle stored procedure error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748041/pls-00103-oracle-stored-procedure-error)

Your procedure needs a BEGIN and an END.